# Query to get unique status from tracking table for a given time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have scenario to select unique value present in tracking table for a given time

Table values like,

[image]

```
HistoryId   EmpId   RoleName    TimeStamp
1   1   Developer   8:00:00 AM
2   1   Lead        8:00:00 PM
3   1   Mgr         5:00:00 PM
4   2   Lead        8:00:00 AM
5   2   Developer2  5:00:00 PM
6   2   Mgr2        8:00:00 PM
7   3   Mgr         8:00:00 AM
8   3   Lead2       5:00:00 PM
9   3   Developer3  8:00:00 PM
11  3   Developer4  8:30:00 PM
12  1   lead5       8:15:00 PM
```

Want to select the unique RoleName values for user for a given time,

Example - If I pass time as 6PM, it should select latest status of each user at 6PM

I have tried to select as below, but it is given all the values, where as I need only latest values present for the time value passed

```
Select  EmpId, RoleName, MAX(TimeStamp)
From [dbo].[EmpRoleHistory]
Where TimeStamp <= '2020-02-06 18:00:00.000'
GROUP BY EmpId, RoleName
ORDER BY EmpId
```

Expected Result:

```
1   Mgr         2020-02-06 17:00:00.000
2   Developer2  2020-02-06 17:00:00.000
3   Lead2       2020-02-06 17:00:00.000
```

Current Result:

```
1   Developer   2020-02-06 08:00:00.000
1   Mgr         2020-02-06 17:00:00.000
2   Developer2  2020-02-06 17:00:00.000
2   Lead        2020-02-06 08:00:00.000
3   Lead2       2020-02-06 17:00:00.000
3   Mgr         2020-02-06 08:00:00.000
```

Comment: You should give us sample data with the corresponding result as text instead of image

Comment: so selecting the recent user and timestamp before 5pm or after?

Comment: @Phong added sample data in text

Comment: @maSTAShuFu  Latest status at any given time, like if I pass as 5PM and particular user had multiple updates for a day, I want to see the status he had at 5PM

Comment: How about **current result** and the **expected result**?

Comment: @Phong added now

Comment: I've just updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60106659/9071943), take a look at @Pradeep H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
GROUP BY EmpId, RoleName
```

As I can see, the same `EmpId` have different from `RoleName`.

So that's the reason why you are getting different values.

[demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e7567dfb51f283c354990e22dbe9c404)

```
 ;with cte_TempTable as
(
Select  EmpId, MAX(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp
From [dbo].[EmpRoleHistory]
Where TimeStamp <= '2020-02-06 17:00:00.000'
GROUP BY EmpId
)
select e.*
from EmpRoleHistory e
inner join cte_TempTable c on e.EmpId = c.EmpId
where e.TimeStamp = c.TimeStamp
ORDER BY e.EmpId
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery and not exists

```
with cte as
(
Select  EmpId, RoleName, TimeStamp
From [dbo].[EmpRoleHistory]
Where TimeStamp <= '2020-02-06 17:00:00.000'
)
select * from cte a
where not exists
(
select 1 from cte b where a.EmpId= b.EmpId and a.TimeStamp < b.TimeStamp
)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, the above query also selecting all values before the time passed. Is there a way to do this without sub query, in real scenario I have a huge table, subquery may affect the performance to generate this report

Comment: PradeepH, test it first. CTE acually are quite performant. And the query in my answer only gives one row per empID.

Comment: My bad, sub query select had RoleName in where, Getting Correct result with empId

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery or CTE to return the latest EmpRoleHistory record for each employee prior to the supplied datetime, and then join the subquery to the main table to pull out the RoleName value for those records.

```
Select erh.EmpId, erh.RoleName, erh.TimeStamp
From [dbo].[EmpRoleHistory] as erh
Inner Join (
    Select  EmpId, MAX(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp
    From [dbo].[EmpRoleHistory]
    Where TimeStamp <= '2020-02-06 18:00:00.000'
    GROUP BY EmpId
    ) as filt on erh.EmpId = filt.EmpId and 
erh.TimeStamp = filt.TimeStamp
Order By erh.EmpId
```